# emacs 起動時に自動で設定ファイルを読み込む方法

Tags: emacs

提示の設定ファイルですが起動時に読み込まれず起動のたびに`load-file`コマンドを入力しないといけないことに困っています。毎回起動時に自動で読み込ませるにはどうすればいいのでしょうか？参考書籍を参考にしているのですが設定の反映方法についての記述がないので困っています。

###### 試したこと

提示画像のようにドライブ全体で`init.el`のファイル検索をかけて関連するファイルをすべて削除して再起動

ファイルの場所:
`~/.emacs.d/init.el`

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

参考サイト：
[Emacs についての補足ファイル](https://www.math.s.chiba-u.ac.jp/%7Ematsu/emacs/emacs-aux.html)
[teratailでの中座された質問](https://teratail.com/questions/fd8g33nnfw9ktl)

参考書籍：
[Emacs実践入門 ～思考を直感的にコード化し、開発を加速する (Amazon)](https://www.amazon.co.jp/dp/4774150029/)

###### 設定ファイル

```
(load (expand-file-name "~/.emacs.d/init"))
;;１行づつスクロールする
(setq scroll-step 1)

;;パッケージ
;;; package.el
(require 'package)
;; MELPAを追加
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("melpa" . "https://melpa.org/packages/"))
;; MELPA-stableを追加
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("melpa-stable" . "https://stable.melpa.org/packages/"))
;; Marmaladeを追加
(add-to-list 'package-archives  '("marmalade" . "https://marmalade-repo.org/packages/"))
;; Orgを追加
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("org" . "http://orgmode.org/elpa/"))
;; 初期化
(package-initialize)

;;mozc
(require 'mozc)                                 ; mozcの読み込み
(set-language-environment "Japanese")           ; 言語環境を"japanese"に
(setq default-input-method "japanese-mozc")     ; IMEをjapanes-mozcに
(prefer-coding-system 'utf-8)                   ; デフォルトの文字コードをUTF-8に

;; C++ インデント
(add-hook 'c++-mode-hook'(lambda()(c-set-style "ellemtel")))
(add-hook 'php-mode-hook'(lambda()(c-set-style "ellemtel")))

;;起動時にEmacsメニュー画面を表示しない
(setq inhibit-startup-message t)

;;起動時にメッセージを表示しない
(setq initial-scratch-message "")

/////////////////////////////////////////////////
;; 改行の時のインデント無効
(electric-indent-mode -1)
////////////////////////////////////////////////

;;コメントの色を緑色に
(set-face-foreground 'font-lock-comment-face "green")
  
(global-font-lock-mode t) ;;文字の色つけ

(custom-set-variables
 ;; custom-set-variables was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 '(ansi-color-faces-vector
   [default default default italic underline success warning error])
 '(ansi-color-names-vector
   ["#2e3436" "#a40000" "#4e9a06" "#c4a000" "#204a87" "#5c3566" "#729fcf" "#eeeeec"])
 '(package-selected-packages
   (quote
    (auto-complete dash mozc popup mozc-im mozc-popup mozc-temp ac-mozc))))
(custom-set-faces
 ;; custom-set-faces was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 '(font-lock-function-name-face ((t (:foreground "orange4"))))
 '(font-lock-type-face ((t (:foreground "blue"))))
 '(mouse-drag-and-drop-region ((t (:background "cyan")))))
```

Comment: 「ファイルが読み込まれない」と判断した理由はなんですか？あと`C-h v user-init-file`や`C-h v user-emacs-directory`の結果を見てみると何か有用な情報が得られるかもしれません。

Answer (score 1):

過去に作成した、`~/.emacs.el` や `~/.emacs` ファイルが残っているということはないでしょうか。
マニュアルによると上述のファイルは、`~/.emacs.d/init.el` よりも優先されますが、後続の初期化ファイルは読み込まれないため、これらのファイルが邪魔をしていることも考えられます。
優先されるファイルが存在する場合は、これらを削除するか、リネームすれば、`~/.emacs.d/init.el`が読み込まれることになります。

The Emacs Editor: 49.4.4 How Emacs Finds Your Init File
https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Find-Init.html

Comment: 質問を更新しました。ドライブ全体で検索をかけて関連するファイルをすべて削除しましたが変わりませんｗ